# "invalid_client" in Spring Security when using private_key_jwt instead of client_secret_basic

Tags: spring-security, openid-connect, spring-security-oauth2

I have tried to switch from client_secret_basic to private_key_jwt, but I'm getting the following error when I'm sent back from the auth provider:
[invalid_client] Client authentication failed. No client authentication included

It's not a Spring Boot app, but this is what I have done so far:

```
private ClientRegistration idPortenClientRegistration() {
  return ClientRegistrations
    .fromIssuerLocation("the endpoint")
    .clientId("the client id")
    .registrationId("idporten")
    .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
    .redirectUri("the redirect url")
    .scope(Arrays.asList("the scopes"))
    .userNameAttributeName(IdTokenClaimNames.SUB)
    .clientName("idporten")
    .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.PRIVATE_KEY_JWT);
    .build();
}
```

My SecurityConfig.class:

```
http.oauth2Client(oauth2 -> oauth2
  .authorizationCodeGrant(codeGrant -> codeGrant
    .accessTokenResponseClient(accessTokenResponseClient())));
```

[…]

```
private DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient accessTokenResponseClient() {
  OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequestEntityConverter requestEntityConverter = new OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequestEntityConverter();
  requestEntityConverter.addParametersConverter(
  new NimbusJwtClientAuthenticationParametersConverter<>(jwkResolver));

  DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient tokenResponseClient = new DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient();
  tokenResponseClient.setRequestEntityConverter(requestEntityConverter);
  return tokenResponseClient;
}

private Function<ClientRegistration, JWK> jwkResolver = (clientRegistration) -> {
  if (clientRegistration.getClientAuthenticationMethod().equals(ClientAuthenticationMethod.PRIVATE_KEY_JWT)) {
    JKSKeyManager keyManager = getApplicationContext().getBean("keyManager", JKSKeyManager.class);
    try {
      RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyManager.getPublicKey("idporten1");
      KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry pkEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) keyManager.getKeyStore()
        .getEntry("idporten1", new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(keyEntryPassword1.toCharArray()));
      RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) pkEntry.getPrivateKey();
      return new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey).privateKey(privateKey).keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString()).build();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnrecoverableEntryException | KeyStoreException e) {
      logger.error("Failed to configure jwkResolver: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
  }
  return null;
};
```

As mentioned, I'm successfully redirected to the auth provider, but getting the error described above when I'm sent back to the application. I have also tried to log accessTokenResponseClient() and jwkResolver. The former method gets called just before the error occurs, but nothing gets logged from the latter.

Some documentation from the provider:
https://docs.digdir.no/oidc_protocol_token.html
https://oidc-ver2.difi.no/idporten-oidc-provider/.well-known/openid-configuration

Comment: `new NimbusJwtClientAuthenticationParametersConverter<>(jwkResolver);` does not seem to do anything. Did you mean `requestEntityConverter.addParametersConverter(new NimbusJwtClientAuthenticationParametersConverter<>(jwkResolver));`?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I am running into the same problem.

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg, thanks for your comment. I'll take a further look next week and get back to both of you. :)

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg: Actually, there is a typo in the code example above. I have already your suggestion in my code, but same error.

Comment: Sorry about that. It seems you're mostly following the [example in the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/client/client-authentication.html#oauth2Client-jwt-bearer-auth) but it's difficult to tell for certain. Can you place breakpoints or sysouts in your `jwkResolver` and see what's happening in there?

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg, interesting. Nothing is logged inside the jwkResolver, but I also placed a log line in the accessTokenResponseClient() method, just before `requestEntityConverter.addParametersConverter`. This is logged. I'm not very familiar with Functions in Java, so maybe it's possible to rewrite the code and remove it.

Comment: Here's a [screenshot of the logging](https://folk.universitetetioslo.no/erlendfg/s-shot-id-porten.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The `NimbusJwtClientAuthenticationParametersConverter` does not work at all. `x5c` and `kid` claims are just ignored, so I ended up with my own converter. And it is so small and simple, so I will share it here.

But first of all – there was one mistake in my previous code, so the converter was never called. Here is what you have to add in the security config:
`http.oauth2Login() .tokenEndpoint().accessTokenResponseClient(accessTokenResponseClient());`

My simple converter just deals with a signed JWT and nothing else:

```
public class SignedJwtClientAuthenticationParametersConverter<T extends AbstractOAuth2AuthorizationGrantRequest>
        implements Converter<T, MultiValueMap<String, String>> {

    private static final String CLIENT_ASSERTION_TYPE_VALUE = "urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer";

    private final Function<ClientRegistration, String> jwt;

    public SignedJwtClientAuthenticationParametersConverter(
            final Function<ClientRegistration, String> jwt) {
        this.jwt = jwt;
    }


    @Override
    public MultiValueMap<String, String> convert(final T authorizationGrantRequest) {
        ClientRegistration clientRegistration = authorizationGrantRequest.getClientRegistration();

        String jwt = this.jwt.apply(clientRegistration);

        MultiValueMap<String, String> parameters = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        parameters.set(OAuth2ParameterNames.CLIENT_ASSERTION_TYPE, CLIENT_ASSERTION_TYPE_VALUE);
        parameters.set(OAuth2ParameterNames.CLIENT_ASSERTION, jwt);

        return parameters;
    }
}
```

And here is the accessTokenResponseClient bean:

```
@Bean
public OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient<OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequest> accessTokenResponseClient() {
        OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequestEntityConverter requestEntityConverter = new OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequestEntityConverter();

        requestEntityConverter.addParametersConverter(
                new SignedJwtClientAuthenticationParametersConverter<>(jwkResolver));

        DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient accessTokenResponseClient = new DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient();
        accessTokenResponseClient.setRequestEntityConverter(requestEntityConverter);
        return accessTokenResponseClient;
    }

    private Function<ClientRegistration, String> jwkResolver = (clientRegistration) -> {
        if (clientRegistration.getClientAuthenticationMethod().equals(ClientAuthenticationMethod.PRIVATE_KEY_JWT)) {
            try {
                return getJwtByClientRegistration(clientRegistration);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Failed to sign JWT: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
        return null;
    };
```

The method `getJwtByClientRegistration()` is now shown, but here I am using the JOSE library, which I am more familiar with.